# Disassemble exe file after compilation with gcc

Tags: gcc, binary

This made One week i search for a solution, please help me.

This is my source code: `myexe.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* gcc -m32 -o myexe myexe.c */

int main(void) 
{
    system("ls /home/myexe"); 
    return 0;
}
```

After complilation, I want to disassemble `myexe` and change `ls /home/myexe` to `cat /home/myexe` in the assembly code.

It is a exercice I received. Please help me!

`myexe` output:

```
ch11:     format de fichier elf64-x86-64


Déassemblage de la section .init :

0000000000000530 <_init>:
 530:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 534:   48 8b 05 a5 0a 20 00    mov    0x200aa5(%rip),%rax        # 200fe0 <__gmon_start__>
 53b:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 53e:   74 02                   je     542 <_init+0x12>
 540:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 542:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 546:   c3                      retq   

Déassemblage de la section .plt :

0000000000000550 <.plt>:
 550:   ff 35 b2 0a 20 00       pushq  0x200ab2(%rip)        # 201008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 556:   ff 25 b4 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200ab4(%rip)        # 201010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 55c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000560 <system@plt>:
 560:   ff 25 b2 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200ab2(%rip)        # 201018 <system@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 566:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
 56b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   550 <.plt>

Déassemblage de la section .plt.got :

0000000000000570 <.plt.got>:
 570:   ff 25 82 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a82(%rip)        # 200ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 576:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax

Déassemblage de la section .text :

0000000000000580 <_start>:
 580:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 582:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
 585:   5e                      pop    %rsi
 586:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
 589:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
 58d:   50                      push   %rax
 58e:   54                      push   %rsp
 58f:   4c 8d 05 aa 01 00 00    lea    0x1aa(%rip),%r8        # 740 <__libc_csu_fini>
 596:   48 8d 0d 33 01 00 00    lea    0x133(%rip),%rcx        # 6d0 <__libc_csu_init>
 59d:   48 8d 3d 0c 01 00 00    lea    0x10c(%rip),%rdi        # 6b0 <main>
 5a4:   ff 15 2e 0a 20 00       callq  *0x200a2e(%rip)        # 200fd8 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 5aa:   f4                      hlt    
 5ab:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

00000000000005b0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
 5b0:   48 8d 3d 79 0a 20 00    lea    0x200a79(%rip),%rdi        # 201030 <__TMC_END__>
 5b7:   48 8d 05 79 0a 20 00    lea    0x200a79(%rip),%rax        # 201037 <__TMC_END__+0x7>
 5be:   55                      push   %rbp
 5bf:   48 29 f8                sub    %rdi,%rax
 5c2:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5c5:   48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
 5c9:   76 15                   jbe    5e0 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
 5cb:   48 8b 05 fe 09 20 00    mov    0x2009fe(%rip),%rax        # 200fd0 <_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable>
 5d2:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 5d5:   74 09                   je     5e0 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
 5d7:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 5d8:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
 5da:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 5e0:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 5e1:   c3                      retq   
 5e2:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 5e6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 5ed:   00 00 00 

00000000000005f0 <register_tm_clones>:
 5f0:   48 8d 3d 39 0a 20 00    lea    0x200a39(%rip),%rdi        # 201030 <__TMC_END__>
 5f7:   48 8d 35 32 0a 20 00    lea    0x200a32(%rip),%rsi        # 201030 <__TMC_END__>
 5fe:   55                      push   %rbp
 5ff:   48 29 fe                sub    %rdi,%rsi
 602:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 605:   48 c1 fe 03             sar    $0x3,%rsi
 609:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
 60c:   48 c1 e8 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rax
 610:   48 01 c6                add    %rax,%rsi
 613:   48 d1 fe                sar    %rsi
 616:   74 18                   je     630 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
 618:   48 8b 05 d1 09 20 00    mov    0x2009d1(%rip),%rax        # 200ff0 <_ITM_registerTMCloneTable>
 61f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 622:   74 0c                   je     630 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
 624:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 625:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
 627:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 62e:   00 00 
 630:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 631:   c3                      retq   
 632:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 636:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 63d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000640 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
 640:   80 3d e9 09 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x2009e9(%rip)        # 201030 <__TMC_END__>
 647:   75 27                   jne    670 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x30>
 649:   48 83 3d a7 09 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x2009a7(%rip)        # 200ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 650:   00 
 651:   55                      push   %rbp
 652:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 655:   74 0c                   je     663 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x23>
 657:   48 8b 3d ca 09 20 00    mov    0x2009ca(%rip),%rdi        # 201028 <__dso_handle>
 65e:   e8 0d ff ff ff          callq  570 <.plt.got>
 663:   e8 48 ff ff ff          callq  5b0 <deregister_tm_clones>
 668:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 669:   c6 05 c0 09 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x2009c0(%rip)        # 201030 <__TMC_END__>
 670:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
 672:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 676:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 67d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000680 <frame_dummy>:
 680:   48 8d 3d 61 07 20 00    lea    0x200761(%rip),%rdi        # 200de8 <__JCR_END__>
 687:   48 83 3f 00             cmpq   $0x0,(%rdi)
 68b:   75 0b                   jne    698 <frame_dummy+0x18>
 68d:   e9 5e ff ff ff          jmpq   5f0 <register_tm_clones>
 692:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 698:   48 8b 05 49 09 20 00    mov    0x200949(%rip),%rax        # 200fe8 <_Jv_RegisterClasses>
 69f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 6a2:   74 e9                   je     68d <frame_dummy+0xd>
 6a4:   55                      push   %rbp
 6a5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6a8:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 6aa:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 6ab:   e9 40 ff ff ff          jmpq   5f0 <register_tm_clones>

00000000000006b0 <main>:
 6b0:   55                      push   %rbp
 6b1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6b4:   48 8d 3d 99 00 00 00    lea    0x99(%rip),%rdi        # 754 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 6bb:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          callq  560 <system@plt>
 6c0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 6c5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 6c6:   c3                      retq   
 6c7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 6ce:   00 00 

00000000000006d0 <__libc_csu_init>:
 6d0:   41 57                   push   %r15
 6d2:   41 56                   push   %r14
 6d4:   41 89 ff                mov    %edi,%r15d
 6d7:   41 55                   push   %r13
 6d9:   41 54                   push   %r12
 6db:   4c 8d 25 f6 06 20 00    lea    0x2006f6(%rip),%r12        # 200dd8 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>
 6e2:   55                      push   %rbp
 6e3:   48 8d 2d f6 06 20 00    lea    0x2006f6(%rip),%rbp        # 200de0 <__init_array_end>
 6ea:   53                      push   %rbx
 6eb:   49 89 f6                mov    %rsi,%r14
 6ee:   49 89 d5                mov    %rdx,%r13
 6f1:   4c 29 e5                sub    %r12,%rbp
 6f4:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 6f8:   48 c1 fd 03             sar    $0x3,%rbp
 6fc:   e8 2f fe ff ff          callq  530 <_init>
 701:   48 85 ed                test   %rbp,%rbp
 704:   74 20                   je     726 <__libc_csu_init+0x56>
 706:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
 708:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 70f:   00 
 710:   4c 89 ea                mov    %r13,%rdx
 713:   4c 89 f6                mov    %r14,%rsi
 716:   44 89 ff                mov    %r15d,%edi
 719:   41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
 71d:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
 721:   48 39 dd                cmp    %rbx,%rbp
 724:   75 ea                   jne    710 <__libc_csu_init+0x40>
 726:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 72a:   5b                      pop    %rbx
 72b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 72c:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
 72e:   41 5d                   pop    %r13
 730:   41 5e                   pop    %r14
 732:   41 5f                   pop    %r15
 734:   c3                      retq   
 735:   90                      nop
 736:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 73d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000740 <__libc_csu_fini>:
 740:   f3 c3                   repz retq 

Déassemblage de la section .fini :

0000000000000744 <_fini>:
 744:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 748:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 74c:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Hint: Try to make `gcc` output the assembler file (read the `man` page).

Comment: What tools do you know? Evidently `objdump` since you used it. What else? This is not a simple exercise if you start knowing nothing, but you must have been taught things in class.

Comment: I suppose this challenge is from root-me, right?

Comment: Why don't you share the command you used to disassemble?

Comment: @Gilles Your right thanks for formatting for me. I 'm new on this site. I use gdb ,nasm and gcc. I used objdump to dump to disassembly. and gdb to debug the program, gcc to compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disassemble your program you can use any of the large number of free and paid disassemblers that are out there.

If you simply want to change the command run by `system`, you do not need to disassemble the program.  You can simply use a hex editor to modify the binary.

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: Hex editor would be only easy if the new string has the same length.

Comment: The exercise asks to change `ls` to `cat`, which is longer. This is probably on purpose to avoid the simple solution with a binary editor.

Comment: @rudimeier. Not true. The trivial case is if the new string is the same length or shorter.  Shorter - just pad with nulls.  Far far more difficult case is when the new string is longer than the original.  You have  to calculate new offsets and addresses and play with ELF structures.

Comment: @Gilles, I concur.